# React functional component param

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, react-functional-component

I am trying to factorize my code and creating a functional component that takes as a parameter a custom struct.

```js
export type Product = {
    Name: string;
    Category?: string;
};
```

```js
export default function ProductCard (product: Product) {
  return(
    <Card sx={{margin: "30px", padding:"20px", width:"20%"}}>
        <CardMedia component="img" height="200" src="image.png"></CardMedia>
        <Typography variant="h6">{product.Name}</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h6">{product.Category}</Typography>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Using it in an other page like that:

```html
<ProductCard product={products[0]}/>
```

Throws me the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ product: Product; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Product'.
  Property 'product' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Product'.
```

Comment: Your `ProductCard` components expects props with `product`. Currently, you are saying `ProductCard` takes a `Name` and a `Category`. You want to define a new type/interface containing a `product` prop: `export type ProductCardProps = { product: Product; }` --> `function ProductCard(({ product }): ProductCardProps) {`

Comment: Another way, you can define `Interface of Props` for a components is like this: `const ProductCard : React.FC<Product > = ({ product }) { return ....}; export default ProductCard;   `